# How can I maintain my last command’s exit-status while resetting my prompt in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, exit-code, zshrc, zsh-zle

I’m trying to make an über-simple (single-character) prompt that gives me as much information as possible. Here’s what I have at the moment (had it for ages, can’t remember where I found the original):

```
# RPS1="['%1v', '%2v', '%3v', '%4v', '%5v', '%6v', '%7v', '%8v', '%9v']" # debug
PS1=" %(?|%2F|%1F)%1(V|%1v|%(#|#|:))%(?|%2f|%1f) "

function zle-line-init {
  zle -K vicmd
}
zle -N   zle-line-init

function zle-keymap-select {
  psvar[1]="${${KEYMAP/(main|viins)/>}/vicmd/}"
  zle reset-prompt
  psvar[1]=""
}
zle -N   zle-keymap-select
```

This is fairly simple; it initializes the prompt into command mode on rendering, and displays a `:` prompt when in the vi’s “command” mode, and a `>` prompt (by changing `psvar[1]`) when in vi’s “insert” mode. In addition, the `:` is replaced with `#` if you are acting as root, and the color of the character exhibits the exit status of the last command.

#### My problem:

When the keymap changes (that is, when I toggle through the “command” and “insert” modes using, as an example, `a` and then the escape key, the `$?` exit-status is overtrodden with a successful `0` status, thus causing the prompt to display in green instead of red (even if the previous command failed). How can I save or set the prompt such that the `%(?|…|…)` portions of `$PS1` will properly display the exit status of the *last command sent to the shell*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following answer from Bart Schaefer on the `zsh-users` mailing list. It works!

> This was fixed in July 2010, so eventually you won't need to do anything:
>
> ```
>    * users/15217: Src/Zle/zle_main.c: use top-level status when redrawing prompt.
> ```
>
> In the meantime, try this:
>
> function zle-keymap-select {
>       local Q=$?
>       psvar[1]="${${KEYMAP/(main|viins)/>}/vicmd/}"
>       (return $Q)
>       zle reset-prompt
>       psvar[1]=""
>     }
>
> If your zsh is recent enough to have anonymous functions, you can replace the subshell `(return $Q)` with `(){ return $Q }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function zle-keymap-select {
  local saved_exitcode=$?
  psvar[1]="${${KEYMAP/(main|viins)/>}/vicmd/}"
  zle reset-prompt
  psvar[1]=""
  return $saved_exitcode
}
```

Comment: That’s the first thing I tried! ;D It doesn’t actually solve the problem, though. The return value of the hook function itself seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
oldexitcode=$?
∶
# do stuff...
∶
( exit $oldexitcode )
```

Comment: See my comment on Phil P’s answer “above.” Doesn’t work either. )-: